# python 3.5 / I'm trying to plot images in a folder I have in python and draw a box on each one then close it and open the next one

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, opencv

python 3.5 / I'm trying to plot images in a folder I have in python and draw a box on each one then close it and open the next one.
it gets stuck in the for loop and keeps opening all the images at once over and over again, then the kernel dies.
I'm working on anaconda's spyder.
this is the code

```
 def line_select_callback(clk, rls):
    global tl_list
    global br_list
    tl_list.append((int (clk.xdata),int (clk.ydata)))
    br_list.append((int (rls.xdata),int (rls.ydata)))
    object_list.append(obj)


def onkeypress(event):
    global object_list
    global tl_list
    global br_list
    global img
    if event.key == 'q':
       write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl_list, br_list, savedir)
       tl_list = []
       br_list = []
       object_list = []
       img = None
       plt.close()

def toggle_selector(event):
    toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n, image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
        img = image_file
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        #mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        ax.imshow(image)  
        toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(
                ax, line_select_callback,
                drawtype = 'box',useblit = True,
                button = [1], minspanx = 5, minspany = 5,
                spancoords = 'pixels', interactive = True
                )
        bbox = plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
        key = plt.connect('key_press_event', onkeypress)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: (What are you using `n`/`enumerate` for?)

Comment: I'm using it as a counter, at first I thought it was unnecessary but when I removed it I got the following error :     image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'path' @greybeard

Comment: @greybeard can you think of anything on why this is happening?

Comment: Edit your question in favour of commenting comments: this is not chat. As an example: Does *this* in `why this is happening` refer to `it gets stuck in the for loop and …` or to `'tuple' object has no attribute 'path'`? (The latter would be simple: `os.scandir()` returns an iterator over `os.DirEntry`, suggested use: `with os.scandir(image_folder) as des:
    for image_file in des:`)